# Create JSF form based on object dynamically from JSFManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to create UI components dynamically in JSF page using managed bean. I have UI types(inputText,textArea,Calender,combobox, etc...) stored in the database. So using these data I want to create UI components such as textfields on JSF page.

Is it possible, if yes then how can I do this? This question has been asked 4 years ago and already has an answer but not compatible with my case because I use JSF pages .xhtml version JSF2.0

Any hints gratefully appreciated!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gke4dbW-5zg
Look at the video as he is creating forms and inputs dynamically

Comment: You was being confused/misled by the irrelevant Seam/Lombok noise in that duplicate question. I've cleaned up that question. The answer remains unchanged for JSF 2.x.